# Upgrade project from swift1.x to swift2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

after modifying lots of code for swift2, remove lots of error.
and finally it shows swiftc failed with exit code 1

and I got this error as well...

```
Invalid bitcast
  %16 = bitcast i32 %15 to %CSo15NSManagedObject*, !dbg !252
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

any idea on how can I locate the broken function??

Comment: Add exception breakpoint. see where the crush at

Comment: XCode does the conversion for you when you open a project using swift 1 in XCode 7.

Comment: @roimulia still the same :(

Comment: Strange. Automatic conversion worked on my project.

Comment: may be there is problem with my libraries...

Comment: Even if it didn't do it automatically, you can still ask Xcode to help you update your code to Swift 2 by opening Menu Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixing all the errors manually, you should do it automatically. See attached image.

[image]